# Is "a frenzy of" only followed by verbs?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, phrase-usage

Is saying "They were **sent into a frenzy of theories** after the spoilers for the movie came out" grammatically incorrect?

I looked up some examples of how you use **send/sent into a frenzy of**, and in most cases, **frenzy of** was followed by a verb. **The audience was sent into a frenzy of singing.**
So, keeping that in mind, is saying **"sent into a frenzy of theories"** correct?

Answer (score 2):

"Frenzy of" often takes a gerund object, but it is not limited to that. Searching Google Books for ["frenzy of contortions"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22frenzy%20of%20contortions%22), for example, provides several examples, such as [this one](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Glorious_Dawn/PDxRAvoOAEQC?gbpv=1&dq=%22frenzy%20of%20contortions%22&pg=PT285):

> With cold-blooded determination the mustang went into a frenzy of contortions, and Johanna held her breath as Burr was whipped back and forth. (Dorothy Garlock, "Glorious Dawn," Grand Central Publishing, 2001)

Answer (score 1):

You've asked two questions.

1. **Is "a frenzy of" only followed by verbs?**

No, other parts of speech can follow also. See [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22in%20the%20OR%20a%20frenzy%20of%22&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALiCzsbD7wVIP9z16yIXAYAH9jSBazMHDA%3A1667930407549&ei=J5lqY7CUIbiWkPIPk_WvsAQ&ved=0ahUKEwjww877lJ_7AhU4C0QIHZP6C0YQ4dUDCAk&uact=5&oq=%22in%20the%20OR%20a%20frenzy%20of%22&gs_lcp=Cg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzEAMyBQghEKsCUABYAGCmBmgAcAB4AIABYogBYpIBATGYAQDAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz-books) for a search in Google books, and [here](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/frenzy?q=frenzy) for some examples from a dictionary.

2. **Is saying "They were sent into a frenzy of theories after the spoilers for the movie came out" grammatically incorrect?**

No, it's not incorrect, but it's a little strange. Theories are merely a sort of explanation or belief. In this case, I don't see how *the theories themselves* would be in a frenzy. Instead, I would think that *the people developing the theories* are *doing so* in a frenzy, which isn't quite the same thing.